# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Arises when using Tesseract with OpenCv

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, opencv, tesseract

i have my iPhone app(XCODE 4.3.2) raises an EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception although i have a clean build and analyze also no zombie objects exists, what's the reasons of these exception could be?, i'm using tesseract OCR engine and integrates it with OpenCv library for image preprocessing, tesseract alone works well but when i integrates it with OpenCv, EXC_BAD_ACCESS is raised, how to resolve this problem,thanks.
Hint: tesseract OCR engine is completely written in C++.

Comment: Set a breakpoint for exceptions and post the console message and/or the stack trace.  If that doesn't give extra information, catch the exception and log it along with callStackSymbols. Without more information, there are too many possibilities.

Comment: i tried to put a breakpoint also tried to catch it using @try&@catch but no more information about the exception appeared in the log!!